# Can The VMs in Azure Lab Service have internet Connection?

Tags: azure, service

I am looking for a cloud enviroment for teaching some network and IT Pro training courses. Before i try the Azure Lab Services, can you tell me if the VMs can have Internet Access or the VMs will just connect with another VMs in the same lab?

Answer (score 1):

Your lab VMs should have internet access.  If you need to control traffic more tightly, or you need the Lab VMs to connect to network attached resources in another VNET, you can connect the Labs account to an existing VNET with VNET peering.

See here for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/classroom-labs/how-to-connect-peer-virtual-network